# NSIS. Force quit installer

Tags: nsis

I defined custom abort functio and want to quit installer in it.

```
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT customOnUserAbort

Function customOnUserAbort
    Quit (or Abort) #no matter
FunctionEnd
```

Also I have a custom page where executes long live procedures in background in `MyCustomLeave` (when leaving the page) function

```
Function MyCustomLeave
    ShowWindow $UnderTopLabel 0
    ShowWindow $UnderTopLabel2 1

    EnableWindow $CustomNext.Button 0

    EnableWindow $RADIO1 0
    EnableWindow $RADIO_LABEL1 0
    EnableWindow $RADIO2 0
    EnableWindow $RADIO_LABEL2 0
    ShowWindow $GROUP1 ${SW_HIDE}

    ${NSD_LV_GetCheckState} $GROUP1 $unpackIndex $Checkbox_StateUnpackIndex

    ${NSD_LV_GetCheckState} $GROUP1 $hpIndex $Checkbox_StateSetUpHomepage
     ${if} $Checkbox_StateSetUpHomepage == 1
        StrCpy $ChangeHomepage 1
     ${else}
        StrCpy $ChangeHomepage 0
     ${endif}

    ${NSD_LV_GetCheckState} $GROUP1 $searchIndex $Checkbox_StateSetUpSearch
     ${if} $Checkbox_StateSetUpSearch == 1
        StrCpy $ChangeSearch 1
     ${else}
        StrCpy $ChangeSearch 0
     ${endif}

    ${NSD_LV_GetCheckState} $GROUP1 $ntIndex $Checkbox_StateSetUpNewTabPage
     ${if} $Checkbox_StateSetUpNewTabPage == 1
        StrCpy $ChangeNewTabPage 1
     ${else}
        StrCpy $ChangeNewTabPage 0
     ${endif}

     /*CUSTOM_PAGE_SOFT_3*/

    Call ValidateCheckedExtraSoft

    GetFunctionAddress $0 **workerfunc**
    BgWorker::CallAndWait #in background
FunctionEnd
```

When I click on the top right cross button a `customOnUserAbort` function is called and a new clear gray window opens but installer is not quit until **workerfunc** is finished.

How to force quit an installer? Or how to disable red cross button?
Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you showing us all the ListView stuff that we don't need to know but you are not showing use the workerfunc? Please provide a smaller example that fully reproduces the problem...

Comment: It does not matter what function ... I ask you the reasons why the installation program can not be stopped immediately.

Comment: It cannot be stopped immediately because you called a function called CallAndWait. The BgWorker plugin was not designed to be used in a leave function. You should not perform actions that take a long time in the leave page callbacks...

Comment: Give me an advice please how it will be better to do